# psql equivalent for pg_restore for .sql files

Tags: postgresql, psql, pg-dump, pg-restore

I ONLY dump my databases as *.sql files not *.dump files. As a result NONE of the `pg_restore` commands work. I've been reading through answers and I swear most people have a reading disability lol

I am asking for the equivalent in `psql` for a common `pg_restore` commandLine method to restore a database.
I have no intention of dumping my databases as *.dump.

my question is this:
what is the equivalent to: 
`pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U myuser -d my_db db/latest.dump`
using `psql`

so...

something along the lines of:
`psql --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U myuser -d my_db db/latest.sql`

Comment: there's no equivalent. `psql  -h localhost -U myuser -d my_db 
 -f db/latest.sql` should work

Comment: I thought so as well tbh, however, it seems I need to drop schema's, functions, tables, key_values etc as the attempt won't work as those items already exist... 

other than going into the *.sql file itself and rewriting the entire thing...

which means there must be a better way to dump with `pg_dump` to a *.sql file with the drop if exists command

Comment: if you need logic on backup file - use custom pg_dump format. If you use plain format - you can't have any logic

Comment: yup, for now I'm just dealing with adding a `DROP TABLE name IF EXISTS;` instead

Answer (score 1):

With a SQL dump you need to decide whether you want to drop target objects, when *dumping* the database, not when importing it.

So, you need to use:

```
pg_dump --clean ....
```

Then the SQL dump will contain the necessary `DROP` statements.

Another option is to run [`drop owned by current_user`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-drop-owned.html) before doing the import. This however requires that everything is owned by the user doing the import (so you can't run the import as e.g. `postgres`)

This can be combined with running the SQL dump:

```
psql -U your_user -d your_db -c 'drop owned by current_user' -f your_dump.sql
```